# Issues with KVM switch and xrandr

Tags: linux, display, centos, resolution, kvm-switch

I've got two computers routed through a VGA KVM switch to a 1920x1080 monitor.

The input and output of the KVM are VGA. On one of the computers, there is only a single DVI-I output, so I've attached a DVI-I to VGA converter to it.

For some reason, xrandr doesn't pick up the full resolution on the computer with the adapter, so I've manually added the correct resolution (xrandr only detects a maximum of 1024x768) and force it to that resolution after boot.

But every time I switch away and back to the computer using the KVM switch, xrandr goes back to the 1024x768 resolution. Is there any way to force xrandr to always use only the 1920x1080 resolution?

I'm running CentOS 6.6 x64, if OS is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest forcing screen resolution via xorg.conf:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Configured Screen"
    Monitor       "Configured Monitor"
    Device        "Configured Video Device"
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes     "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Configured Monitor"
    Modeline       "1920x1080" 74.16 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 +HSync +VSync
EndSection
```

You'll probably need a custom modeline, you can generate one with `cvt width height refreshrate`
Don't hesitate to share your xorg.conf file so that specific modification could be suggested.

Here's a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74808/how-do-i-force-a-resolution-of-1024x768) closely related to yours.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. I used cvs to generate and add the new resolution. I'll edit the xorg.conf file and see if it helps, thanks!

Comment: Adding the correct resolution is one thing. If your display still keeps changing resolution, you should also remove the offending mode (1024x768) from the `Modes` line.